# Gnu AS doesn't seem to preprocess #defines, but GCC does

Tags: gcc, assembly, c-preprocessor, gnu-assembler

I have a potentially large number of constants which are used by an increasing number of source files. I need to be able to play around with its value, so it's convenient for it to be defined in one place.

An example of my situation as follows:

The header file where I define the variables, rmode_loc.h:

```
#define __ASSEMBLER__

#define BSEQ_HI 0xF000
#define BSEQ_LO 0x0000
```

An excerpt from some code where they (should) be used, myprog.S:

```
.code16

/* Include constants */
#include "rmode_loc.h"

_start:

    ...

    push    $BSEQ_HI

    ...

    mov $BSEQ_LO, %bx
```

However, upon attempting compilation the linker reports the following errors:

```
myprog.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `BSEQ_HI'
myprog.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `BSEQ_LO'
```

Evidently an attempt is being made to link against these 'symbols' - thus I conclude that the preprocessor did not replace the symbols to values as those indicated by `rmode_loc.h`.

I read on another SO post (can't find the link) where it was mentioned that if the extension of the source file was `.s` no preprocessing would occur, and the suggestion to define `__ASSEMBLER__` was also given - However, this does not seem to be the issue here as all the sources have `.S` extensions and I added a `#define __ASSEMBLY__` in the header.

However, when using GCC as the frontend for compilation, namely `gcc myprog.S -o myprog`, the `BSEQ` labels are correctly replaced, and everything compiles.

My question is, what difference in preprocessing is there when using `as` rather than `gcc` to yield these results, and are there any significant technical differences when using `gcc` to compile assembly code instead of `as`?

Comment: `gcc` pipes the source through the c preprocessor if the extension is `.S` as you have noticed. Then it just invokes `as` on it, so no additional differences there. You can use `gcc -v` to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GNU `as` by itself **never** processes `#define` directives.

A special feature of the `gcc` command is that when given a filename ending in `.S`, it runs the C preprocessor `cpp` on it (which processes `#define` and `#include` and so forth), and then runs `as` on the resulting output.  But when given a filename ending in `.s`, it just runs `as`.

If you want to use C preprocessor directives, you can either name your files `.S` and use the `gcc` command, or name them whatever you want and manually do both passes:

```
cpp foo.s |as -o foo.o -
```